# How can i send multiple value using get_option();

Tags: custom-field, array, options

If suppose I have :-

```
function dr_add_adminp() {

    // Generating dr_theme_options Admin page
    add_menu_page( 'USR THEME OPTIONS', 'User Options', 'manage_options', 'theme_options', 'theme_page', 'dashicons-admin-customizer', 110 );

    // Generating dr_theme Admin Page

    add_submenu_page( 'dr_theme_options', 'Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 'manage_options', 'theme_options', 'theme_page' );
    add_submenu_page( 'dr_theme_options', 'AEAC Options', 'AEAC Options', 'manage_options', 'aeac_options', 'aeac_options' );


 }

 add_action( 'admin_menu', 'dr_add_adminp' );



register_setting( 'a-group', 'a-name' ); 

register_setting( 'a-group', 'a-age' ); 



add_settings_section( 'section-a-options', 'Name', 'someName', 'aoptions' );



add_settings_field( 'a-settings-id', 'Name', 'namefunction', 'aoptions', 'section-a-options' );

add_settings_field( 'a-age-id', 'Age', 'agefunction', 'aoptions', 'section-a-options' );



function someName() {

 echo '<h1>Enter Your Info</h1>';

}


function namefunction() {

  $name = esc_attr(get_option( 'a-name' ));

  echo $usr_name = '<input type="text" id="name" name="a-name" value="' . $name .'">';

}

function agefunction() {

 $age = esc_attr(get_option( 'a-age' ));

 echo $usr_name = '<input type="text" id="age" name="a-age" value="' . $age .'">';

}
```

how can I send multiple values using an array or the best way.